# Is there a system to calculate the angles and positions of a four legged tripod based on a fixed plane

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solid-geometry

What i am asking is, if their exists a system to calculate a four legged tripod.

[For example this table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ENws.jpg)

Continuing with the example, I would like to calculate the position and angle of the four legs based on the tableheight and surface area so that the room between the legs is minimal.

How would one go about that? Do systems that handle these kinds of problems exist, so i can read up on it?

Comment: We need a mathematical model of your fourlegged tripod. Are the legs just lines, or  cylinders (that maybe touch), etcetera.

Comment: @Christian Blatter so the legs would be cuboids, and these cuboids should touch. If you look at the legs from a bird's view you would see a square (in the center) which i'd like to minimize.

Comment: I believe your problem may be related to the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850979/finding-height-on-oblique-pyramid) about finding the height of a pyramid. If you know the altitude, you can find all the other stuff with the Pythagorean theorem and basic trigonometry.